# How can I define the constant for absolute path only once in PHP?

Tags: php, path, constants

I have the following files:

- admin/config.php
- header.php
- index.php
- contact/index.php

Both index.php and contact/index.php call header.php.
And header.php calls admin/config.php which sets the website root path `WEBSITE_HTTP_ROOT`. I need WEBSITE_HTTP_ROOT to be able to provide the link to the main page.

Here is header.php:

```
<?php
require_once('./admin/config.php');
?>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="http://<?php echo WEBSITE_HTTP_ROOT; ?>" id="logo">website</a>
  </div>
```

The line `require_once('./admin/config.php');`
works when called by index.php, but does not work when called by contact/index.php, because the working folder is different.

How can I define the constant for absolute path only once? and be able to call it from anywhere? or how to best avoid the above problem?

Comment: For clarity, i'm assuming your question is really "how can i include config.php from anywhere, without having to manually customise the `require` path to it from each .php file that calls it". The fact that config.php sets constants, i think, is not the relevant part of your question?

Comment: @Ryven Yes I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to always include files using the relative path from the **current php file location** obtainable using `dirname(__FILE__)`.

For example, in `header.php`, you would include `config.php` with:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . './admin/config.php');
```

Then in `index.php`:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . './header.php');
```

and in `contact/index.php`:

```
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '../header.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a base url parameter:

```
define ( 'BASEURL', 'http://www.domain.com' );
```

And then use: `<a href="<?= BASEURL ?>/header.php">`
Or for front page, just

`<a href="<?= BASEURL ?>">`

Otherwise, just reference it as:

```
<a href ="/header.php">
```

or for frontpage:

```
 <a href ="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found a work-around (for now) since I did the include of config.php already in the main index.php, I did not need to re-include the config.php in the header.php.

So following code works fine:

```
<?php
?>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="http://<?php echo WEBSITE_HTTP_ROOT; ?>" id="logo">website</a>
  </div>
```

this does not really answer the question... but it fixes my problem. Might be useful for someone else.